# c++11 Penalty on lambda initialization

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, lambda

given

```
class C;
void do_something_else( std::function< void ( C &)> );


class A1{
   void do_something(C &);

   void test(){ 
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<100; i++)
          do_something_else([this]( C & C_){ this->do_something(C_); } );
   }
};

class A2{
   std::function< void ( C &)> lambda;
   void do_something(C &);

   A2():lambda([this]( C & C_){ this->do_something(C_) ;}){}

   void test(){ 
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<100; i++)
          do_something_else(lambda);
   }  
};
```

Is there a performance difference between `A1::test()` and `A2::test()`

Comment: Just an aside: you should look up type erasure.

Comment: You tell us. What did you measure?

Comment: @KerrekSB A2 was ~4% slower, this was consistent on with multiple loop sizes, and is the complete opposite of what I was expecting.

Comment: @xvan may be this is measure noise? Do you use google microbenchmark framework?

Comment: @user1034749 Checked with gprof, there is a cumulative difference between both calls.

Comment: @xvan Gprof is bad variant in this case, because of it instrument each function, so you measure also gprof internal work, use google benchmark

Comment: Regardless of the quality of your benchmark suite, 4% in a micro-benchmark is not information, it is noise.  4% probably would be overwealmed by code-cache size, differences in branch behavior, or a myriad of other things in a "real use case", where the two versions differ in ways that where not measured by your micro-benchmark.  What you have provided is (weak) evidence that you shouldn't care performance-wise, not that one is faster than the other.

Comment: Compare it also with `do_something_else(const std::function<void(C&)>&)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::function` is mandated to use small object optimization to store small invokables within itself without allocating memory on the free store.

Your lambda is small, so creating a `std::function` from it in a typical type-erasure based implementation involves setting up the rough equivalent of a virtual function table pointer, and doing a placement construct within a memory buffer located within the `std::function` itself.

The size of your lambda is one pointer (the `this`).  The virtual function table is going to be writing another constant (or maybe a few constant pointers, depending on if the implementation "inlines" the vtable within the `std::function` at the cost of size in exchange for locality).

Any non-trivial operation is going to overwhelm the cost of creating such a small `std::function`.

What more, you take the `std::function< void ( C &)>` by-value: this means the first one placement-constructs the `std::function`, while the second copy-constructs it from an existing `std::function`.  Copy-construction could involve using the virtual table to copy the state, but an optimized `std::function` could keep a flag for "trivially copyable state" to avoid that indirection (at the cost of a branch).

Next, compilers might be able to decode what you are doing with your `std::function` by inlining your class instance and unrolling the assignments to memory.  It might even eliminate the existence of the `std::function` completely.  Compilers continue to get better at this sort of thing.

Finally, you note that you saw a 4% performance difference in your microbenchmark.  That is (weak) evidence that there is no significant difference, as differences between the microbenchmark environment and the "real" environment are going to overwealm such a small difference.

Use whichever makes your code more clear.